# Where can I host a node.js chat bot?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I know this isnt coding but i dont know where else to look.
So I've written a chat bot using node.js and the socket.io-client module. Basically it's just a program that auto responds to messages on a chat room also written with node.js. The problem I have is hosting it. I have hosted it on my raspberry pi which works perfectly but isn't ideal as I sometimes want my pi for other things and this bot runs 24/7.
So, I looked around for some free node.js hosting. I found c9.io, heroku and appfog but all of them expect you to host websites with node.js and so aren't setup for my needs. I need a single instance to be always running but these hosts constantly restart and terminate the program causing all sorts of problems for me which wouldn't really be an issue if it was just outputting a web page. 
So, is there anywhere that is suitable for hosting a node.js app like mine?

Answer (score 0):

Have [Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) host it for you. That's what I'm doing with one of my projects. Just create an instance, I used Ubuntu for my OS, then installed Node.js and was good to go.

Comment: I was kinda looking for something that was free if possible

Comment: You are going to be very hard pressed to find a free host for your Node.js app. With Amazon I end up paying $6.38 a month for my hosting, and I have complete control of the instance. That's probably as close as you'll get to free.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation will be to host it on openshift 
https://www.openshift.com/app/account/new

Heroku is also widely used but in their free tier your bot has to "sleep" 6 hours 
https://www.heroku.com/